# Puranas about Brahma of the trimurti

Tags: puranas, brahma

What are the puranas that describe the life of Brahma (the four-headed God)? I want to learn more about him.

Comment: All major Puranas describe the life of Brahma... @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Can u pls tell which major Purana doesn't talk about Brahma???

Answer (score 3):

In the creation chapter of every Purana Brahma occurs.

Here:

> PARÁŚARA.--I will explain to you,
>   Maitreya, listen attentively, **how this
>   deity, the lord of all, created the
>   gods and other beings.
>   Whilst he (Brahmá) formerly, in the
>   beginning of the Kalpas, was.
>   meditating on creation, there
>   appeared a creation beginning with
>   ignorance, and consisting of
>   darkness. From that great being
>   appeared fivefold Ignorance,
>   consisting of obscurity, illusion,
>   extreme illusion, gloom, utter
>   darkness. The creation of the
>   creator thus plunged in
>   abstraction was the fivefold
>   (immovable) the world, without intellect
>   or reflection, void of perception or
>   sensation, incapable of feeling, and
>   destitute of motion .** Since
>   immovable things were first created,
>   this is called the first creation.
>   Brahmá, beholding that it was
>   defective, designed another; and
>   whilst he thus meditated, the
>   animal creation was manifested, to
>   the products of which the term
>   Tiryaksrotas is applied, from their
>   nutriment following a winding
>   course. These were called beasts,
>   & and their character was the
>   quality of darkness, they being
>   destitute of knowledge, uncontrolled
>   in their conduct, and mistaking error
>   for wisdom; being formed of egotism
>   and self-esteem, laboring under
>   the twenty-eight kinds of
>   imperfection, manifesting inward
>   sensations, and associating with
>   each other (according to their
>   kinds).
>
> —**Vishnu Purana:book1:chapter5**

Although in almost every Purana he is mentioned as born of Vishnu or Vishnu's form.

Vishnu form:— http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp038.htm

While almost some oldest Puranas like **Vayu Purana, Matsya Purana**  kurma Purana to supports it Brahma is born from brahmana and Vishnu and Shiva as well

> Creation
>   In the beginning, there was nothing in the
>   universe. There were only darkness and the
>   divine essence (Brahman). It is impossible to
>   describe the Brahman, it has no traits that
>   can be described.
>   When the time came for creation to start, the
>   brahman removed the darkness and divided
>   itself into three. These three parts came to
>   be known as Brahma, Vishnu, and Shiva. The
>   first object that was created was water and
>   Vishnu slept on this water. Since Nara means
>   water and Ayana mean resting-place, Vishnu
>   is accordingly also known as Narayana.
>   In this water next appeared a golden
>   (Hiranya) egg (Anda). The egg shone with the
>   radiance of a thousand suns. Inside the egg,
>   Brahma created himself. Since he effectively
>   created (Bhuva) himself (Svayam), Brahma is
>   also known as Svayambhuva. The egg, you
>   will remember, was golden. Garbha means
>   womb, and since Brahma was born inside a
>   golden egg, he is also known as
>   Hiranyagarbha.
>
> **—Matsya Purana: chapter3**

source:— http://www.bharatadesam.com/spiritual/matsya_purana.php

Comment: "Brahma Purana is the Purana named after Brahma"..most of the places it is written as **ब्रह्म पुराण** and not ब्रह्मा पुराण in Sanskrit and Hindi..And there is huge difference between ब्रह्म and ब्रह्मा..So, can you please post a valid source where it is written as ब्रह्मा पुराण in original Sanskrit text..English translations are misleading sometimes..